# Is it possible to call export function in VPI callback

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions, system-verilog-dpi, vpi

I have the following scenario : I have a vpi callback that is triggered when an assertion is triggered. 
In this callback I want to call an export system verilog function
I tried to setSvScope before the export but simulator gives me some errors.

Comment: which errors did you see? Which simulator?

Comment: I have the following error : DPI Scope function call allowed only from context function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling an DPI exported routine from a routine that has not been DPI imported is left undefined by the 1800-2012 LRM (See section *35.5.3 Context tasks and functions*)

The exported DPI routine when called needs two key pieces of information to behave like any other routine that would have been called by SystemVerilog instead of C. It needs a scope context and a process context.

For the scope, it’s possible to have multiple DPI exports with the same name. In fact, it is possible to have a DPI import/export pair in a module, and that module gets instantiated multiple times. Even though the import calls the same C code, its context gets set from the caller’s scope and that scope gets matched with the exported scope. The DPI provides a `svSetScope` routine to do this explicitly if the implicit DPI imported routine does not.

For the process, there are many things you can do like `disable`, or suspend it. The DPI provides no mechanism to set this explicitly.

Some tools(like Questa) do provide a mechanism to do this for a limited set of use cases. For example, you can only call a DPI exported `function` from non-DPI imported C/C++ code. A task cannot be called because it has the potential to block, and that interferes with any process context.

Comment: Thanks for you help dave_59. I was not aware of this process context.
The tool I'm using is ncsim I have to check if it's possible to explicitly set this process context. My export is a function

Answer (score 0):

Usually when vpi invokes a callback function, there is no DPI contents available at this time. So, you need to look it up  before calling the exported dpi:

```
svScope scope = svGetScopeFromName("path.to.your.export.scope");
svSetScope(scope);
```

where the scope is the one which exports the function. For the exports from the global scope the `$unit` could be used for the scope name.

Comment: Yes vpi callback does not have context information so you have to set it explictly as I understood

I do the following at the beginning of the callback

svSetScope(svGetScopeFromName("common_pkg::"));

My export is defined in the common_pkg